# Retornar doble si el primer dígito es par

Tags: c

Estoy intentando que de 5 dígitos obtenidos, por ej 23456 si el primer dígito es par devuelva 23456*2. Este fue uno de los tantos intentos, ninguno me resulta

```
int main(){
    char* num[4];
    scanf("%s",&num);
    if(putchar(num[0])%2==0){
        printf("%s",num*2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hablas de 5 dígitos pero declaras un array de char de tamaño 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hace mucho que no utilizo C así que mi sintaxis puede ser incorrecta.
Te explico el siguiente código:

```
int main()
{
    char num[5]; //si mal no recuerdo debe de ser 5 para aceptar 5 posiciones aunque el indice llega a 4.
    scanf("%s", num);
    int firstDigit = (int) (num[0] - '0'); //de esta manera se le quitan los digitos del Ascii y se castea a tipo int.
    if(firstDigit % 2 == 0)
    {
        int value = atoi(num) * 2; //la funcion atoi sirve para cambiar un string a numero, sin embargo si no hay digitos devuelve 0 como con "Hola"
        printf("%d", value);
    }
    else
        printf("El primer digito de %s no es par", num); 
}
```

Te dejo un link con la información sobre la función atoi()
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm